# How to redirect output to a file which name is the current date and time and current directory name?

Tags: io-redirection, xterm

I'm trying to redirect with current working directory in xterm.

```
xterm -ls -geometry 80x30 -e 'cd /home/work/test1/; pwd; make | tee test1.log;'
xterm -ls -geometry 80x30 -e 'cd /home/work/temp/test2/; pwd; make | tee test2.log;'
xterm -ls -geometry 80x30 -e 'cd /home/work/tmp/test3/; pwd; make | tee test3.log;'
xterm -ls -geometry 80x30 -e 'cd /home/work/my_test4/; pwd; make | tee my_test4.log;'
xterm -ls -geometry 80x30 -e 'cd /home/work/append/my_test5/; pwd; make | tee my_test5.log;'
...
```

I want to redirect output to a file which name is the current date and time and current last directory name in xterm.

```
for example).
xterm -ls -geometry 80x30 -e 'cd /home/work/append/my_test5/; pwd; make | tee my_test5_03:19:12-11-2023.log;'
```

How to redirect output to a file which name is the current date and time and current directory name in xterm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
xterm -ls -geometry 80x30 -e sh -o errexit -o nounset -c '
  cd -P -- "$1"
  pwd
  make 2>&1 | tee -- "$OLDPWD/${1##*/}_$(date +%FT%T).log"
  ' sh ~/work/test123
```

- explicitly invoke `sh` rather than letting xterm invoke `$SHELL` to interpret what it thinks is shell code
- that also allows us to pass the directory to the shell in a safe manner, here via its first positional parameter
- make sure we abort when command fails by using the `errexit` option so we don't run `make` if `cd` fails for instance. `nounset` added for good measure, but shouldn't be necessary for this simple code.
- the log file is created in the original working directory (the one `xterm` and therefore `sh` was invoked from) by using `$OLDPWD` which `cd` sets to `$PWD` before changing directory.
- redirect both make's stdout and stderr to the pipe so we log the errors as well (note however that the errors will go to `sh`'s stdout via `tee`; no difference here as they both go to the terminal that `xterm` emulates).
- `${1##*/}` expands to `$1` stripped of everything up to the right-most `/`. You could also use `$(basename -- "$1")` which works better if `$1` ends in a `/` but doesn't work properly if it ends in newline.
- use standard YYYY-MM-DDTHH-MM-SS format which is more useful for sorting and less ambiguous.

Note that `tee` will overwrite the file if it existed beforehand, you can add the `-a` option for it to append to it instead.

Note that the exit status of `make` (and `sh`) is lost as `xterm` does not propagate it back to its caller.

Alternative to using the `errexit` is to chain the 3 commands with `&&` instead of just newlines, and to `nounset` to use `${var?error message}` so it all becomes more explicit:

```
xterm -ls -geometry 80x30 -e sh -c '
  cd -P -- "${1?No dir specified}" &&
    pwd &&
    make 2>&1 | tee -- "$OLDPWD/${1##*/}_$(date +%FT%T).log"
  ' sh ~/work/test123
```

Alternative to using `tee` would be to use `zsh` and its `multios` feature allowing to retain separate stdout and stderr streams. There, `$OLDPWD` can also be written `~-` and the timestamp can be computed internally using prompt expansion, and `$var:t` is a proper basename.

```
xterm -ls -geometry 80x30 -e zsh -c '
  cd -P -- "${1?No dir specified}" &&
    pwd &&
    make 3> ~-/${1:t}_${(%):-%D{%FT%T}}.log >&1 >&3 2>&2 2>&3 3>&-
  ' zsh ~/work/test123
```

The exit status of `make` is preserved, though you'd need a terminal emulator that propagates it instead of `xterm` for that to be useful.

Comment: Not working 'make' so I reduce command to find the bug. I declared 'ls' instead of 'make'. but still 'ls' output does not redirect into the new named(date and directory) file.

Comment: @Carter try with `-hold` added to xterm and `-o xtrace` added to sh to see what's going on

Comment: +cd -P -- /home/work/test123 make ++ basename -- /home/work/test123 ++ date +%FT%T   + tee -- test123_2023-12-11T16:48:53.log

Comment: @Carter, looks like you've removed the `$OLDPWD/`, so the log file will be inside `/home/work/test123`

Comment: It also seems like you've joined those 5 lines with one. If you put it all on one line, you'll need to separate the commands with `;`s to replace the newlines. You will also lose in legibility.

Comment: Excellent! problem solved. please do not delete the comments when i forgot them, it will be helpful to remind.